# maven license plugin aggregate licenses from resources

Tags: maven, licensing, pom.xml, dependency-management

We're using the maven license plugin (third-party-aggregate goal) to produce a list of third party project dependencies - this is good and we've got it working. I would like to extend that to include the licenses for our resources (i.e. not just code/dependencies), but don't know where to start - could anyone provide an example of what I need to do to make this work?

An example of what we've got: In a maven modules resources folder we hold a copy of the UK Postcode dataset (as a json file) so that we can use it offline. The file is licensed under Ordnance Survey OpenData license so we've put a LICENSE.txt file in the same directory that states this.

The result I want: "Ordnance Survey OpenData license" to appear in my THIRD-PARTY.txt file.

Some questions to help answer:

1. Can I specify the resource licenses directly in a pom.xml so that I don't have to keep the LICENSE.txt file we've created?
2. Can license-maven-plugin read LICENSE.txt files like the one we're using at the moment?
3. If 2=yes, do I need to specify the format of the text so that license-maven-plugin picks up the license?
4. Do I need to add  tags with the license so that license-maven-plugin picks up these licenses?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the Maven License plugin (with the add-third-party goal) to produce the THIRD-PARTY.txt report for all my Maven modules. I'm not sure this plugin can scan the ressource licenses.

One solution should be to package your json file into a small Maven project. It will produce an artefact and will store it into your binary repository (Artifactory, Nexus, ...).

Next, add a new dependency in your Maven project and the UK Postcode dataset will appear in your THIRD-PARTY.txt report.

Comment: thanks for the answer. That's the way we're probably going to go.